# Bootstrap V3 .Collapse not staying open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So i have recently picked up a site from a friend and i am in the process of rebuilding it using the original bootstrap v3 that was originally put in place. I have added the .collapse class onto a div to hide it away until clicked but when it is clicked the box doesn't stay open just drops down and then immediately goes back to being closed.

If i watch the steps of what happens using the inspect tool in chrome i can see the class starts as 'collapse' changes to 'collapsing' and applies the css styles relevant and then finishes as 'collapse in'. However the box has closed and the 'collapse' class is back to being applied to the div even though it is displaying as 'collapse in'.

```
<div class="collapse" id="facebookreviews">

 <div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
  <imgsrc="img/testimonial.jpg" alt="Testimonial image" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-2">
  <p>After my series of treatments with Inch Go Lipo, I lost 6” off my waist! Thanks Inch Go Lipo!</p>
  <p><strong>Stacey, Shropshire</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
  <img src="img/testimonial.jpg" alt="Testimonial image" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-2">
  <p>After my series of treatments with Inch Go Lipo, I lost 6” off my waist! Thanks Inch Go Lipo!</p>
  <p><strong>Stacey, Shropshire</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
  <img src="img/testimonial.jpg" alt="Testimonial image" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-2">
  <p>After my series of treatments with Inch Go Lipo, I lost 6” off my waist! Thanks Inch Go Lipo!</p>
  <p><strong>Stacey, Shropshire</strong></p>
  </div>

 </div>

</div>

<div class="spacer-25">
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-black" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#facebookreviews" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="facebookreviews">Click to view more
  </button>
 </div>
</div>


.collapse {
display: none;

 &.in      { display: block; }

.collapsing {
 position: relative;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 @include transition-property(height, visibility);
 @include transition-duration(.35s);
 @include transition-timing-function(ease);
 }

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxzTV.png

Answer (score 0):

I loaded your HTML into a file, put the CSS in a CSS, and linked the CSS...

I also put bootstrap 3 css in at the top and jquery and bootstrap.js files in a script tag at the bottom...

I was able to get them to collapse just fine both with putting your collapse div with a container and without a container class.

is jquery and bootstrap.js loaded at the bottom?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="testing.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container collapse" id="facebookreviews">

 <div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
  <imgsrc="img/testimonial.jpg" alt="Testimonial image" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-2">
  <p>After my series of treatments with Inch Go Lipo, I lost 6” off my waist! Thanks Inch Go Lipo!</p>
  <p><strong>Stacey, Shropshire</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
  <img src="img/testimonial.jpg" alt="Testimonial image" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-2">
  <p>After my series of treatments with Inch Go Lipo, I lost 6” off my waist! Thanks Inch Go Lipo!</p>
  <p><strong>Stacey, Shropshire</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
  <img src="img/testimonial.jpg" alt="Testimonial image" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-2">
  <p>After my series of treatments with Inch Go Lipo, I lost 6” off my waist! Thanks Inch Go Lipo!</p>
  <p><strong>Stacey, Shropshire</strong></p>
  </div>

 </div>

</div>

<div class="spacer-25">
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">

  <button class="btn btn-black" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#facebookreviews" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="facebookreviews">Click to view more
  </button>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

[Collapse Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UFez.png)

[Collapse Working Pt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iquqS.png)

Comment: I believe i have the correct srcs loading:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: @James

here is what i used as my html, and responsiveness as well as collapse seems to be working as intended on my chrome browser.

in the head:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="testing.css">` 

and in the body before the `</body>`:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  `

Comment: @james silly question sir but why are you using the jquery UI cdn when bootstrap requires the jquery core?

Comment: this was already in place on the page from the previous person working on the site so i couldn't tell you why it was used originally. This is my first time using bootstrap so my understanding of it is limited if i am honest.

What did you use for it to work correctly?

Comment: @James   change the UI cdn to the jquery core CDN...

     `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>`

jquery UI is more like a framework system built on top of jquery

Comment: If i change mine to the src files you are using then the .collapse does not work at all.

Comment: Is there console errors? Jquery.min.js has to be first and the bootstrap.js second.  As long as the core js is in there you can still keep your jquery UI links as well, your page may be using them for layout or widgets"

Comment: @James my entire code is at the top, editted, with screenshots